# Stripe: Received unknown parameter: receipt_email

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am creating a new Session with stripe and attempting to pass in the `receipt_email` property so that I can explicitely send a reciept to my buyer. The code below works fine without the `receipt_email` property but adding it throws the error: `Received unknown parameter: receipt_email`

```
$session_data = [
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode'=>'payment',
    'billing_address_collection'=> 'auto',
    'line_items'=> [['price' => STRIPE_PRICE, 'quantity'=> 1]],
    'success_url' => URL.'success',
    'cancel_url' => URL.'error',
    'receipt_email' => $email
];

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($session_data);
```

I see that `receipt_email` is actually a property of the `payment_intent`. How/when should I set `receipt_email`?

**Here is the revised $session_data object based on advice from @hmunoz (the chosen answer):**

```
$session_data = [
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode'=>'payment',
    'billing_address_collection'=> 'auto',
    'line_items'=> [['price' => STRIPE_PRICE, 'quantity'=> 1]],
    'success_url' => URL.'success',
    'cancel_url' => URL.'error',
    'payment_intent_data' => ['receipt_email' => $email] //changed this line
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the underlying PaymentIntent's `receipt_email` using `payment_intent_data.receipt_email` field on the CheckoutSession: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-receipt_email

Comment: Is it possible to do in my `$session_data?` If so, how? Or do I need to wait until the checkout session is created and then get the `payment_intent` and set it then? Sorry, I am just trying to understand the workflow...

Comment: check out the link I sent you (no pun intended haha) and the related code snippets, it shows you that `payment_intent_data` is a sub-hash on the CheckoutSession create endpoint. So yes, you would pass it under session_data.